# how to add a userbot to a group by link? python telegram api

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I get a link with which I need to add the bot to a group (private or public) I did not find anything that could help me

my code:

```
link = 'https://t.me/+r....'

client = TelegramClient(session='joiner', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
#login process


result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel=link)) #try to join
#error message (Cannot get entity from a channel (or group) that you are not part of. Join the group and retry)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JoinChannelRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/join_channel.html) is used to join public channels (both broadcast and megagroups are channels). You need the provide the channel itself (or use its username to let the library fetch it for you):

```py
await client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(
    channel='username'
))
```

[`ImportChatInviteRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/import_chat_invite.html) is used to join private chat and channels:

```py
await client(functions.messages.ImportChatInviteRequest(
    hash='A4LmkR23G0IGxBE71zZfo1'
))
```

In this case you need to provide the final part of the invite link, not the entire link.

Comment: what is this hash and where can I get it if I only have a link to the group?

Comment: If your link is `https://t.me/+A4LmkR23G0IGxBE71zZfo1`, the hash is `A4LmkR23G0IGxBE71zZfo1`.